# A mistake in the book "Manga Guide to Calculus"?

Tags: calculus

I am reading now the book “Manga Guide to Calculus” by Hiroyuki Kojima and it seems to me that I found a mistake in it.
The characters of this manga (Noriko Hikima and Kakeru Seki) solve a problem on the cost-effectiveness of TV commercials (pages 31-36).
Doing that, they let us know (on page 33) that “The fee for the TV commercial is 10 million yen per minute”.
Then, on page 35, the question is asked: “How much does it cost to increase the airtime of the commercial by 6 minutes?”
And the answer to this question is given by multiplying: “The fee for the increase is 6 x 0.1 = 0.6 hundred million yen.”

For me, it is nonsense!

In my opinion, they should only multiply 6 x 10 million which gives 60 million yen.
Could somebody explain is that a mistake or not? Maybe, I’ve missed something?

Comment: $0.6$ *hundred* million is $0.6\times 100\times 1000000$ but $60$ million is $60\times1000000$.

Comment: Of course, I agree with you. But I can't understand why they multiply 6 by 0,1 in the book. I find no sense in that.

Comment: 6 is the number of minutes, and 0.1 hundred million is the cost per minute.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cave! That's true. But the text in the book is somewhat misleading...

Comment: In western world, the unit of large number goes in group of thousands, (so thousand, million, billion and so on). For japanese and chinese, the unit of large numbers goes in group of ten thousands (万 'ten thousands', 億 'hundred millions', 兆 'trillons'), the preference in using 0.1 hundred millions instead of ten millions is probably cultural difference which translation fails to capture.

Comment: What I was pointing out is that $0.6$ hundred million yen is the same as $60$ million yen.

Comment: @bjshnog, you are correct.